# Clauses which are not allowed in individual UNION statements

Tags: c#, java, sql, sql-server, database

I am writing a query builder in both C# and Java, and am concerned about generating UNION statements. I am aware that each individual statement in a UNION clause cannot contain an ORDER BY clause, and this must instead be placed at the end of the complete union statement. Are there any other conditions I should be aware of? i.e. conditions which usually apply to single select statements, however cause problems when placed in a `UNION` statement? As far as I can tell, each individual statement can contain GROUP BYs, WHEREs and HAVINGs. Have I missed something?

Comment: The columns and datatypes have to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SQL syntax specification](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html), a select statement returning multiple rows is a query expression followed by an optional `ORDER BY` clause:

```
<direct_select_statement:multiple_rows> ::=
    <query_expression> [ <order_by_clause> ]
```

In turn, query expression is defined as

```
<query_expression> ::= <non-join_query_expression> | <joined_table>
```

and non-join query expression is where the `UNION` is specified:

```
<non-join_query_expression>    ::= 
     <non-join_query_term>
 |     <query_expression> UNION [ ALL ] [ <corresponding_spec> ] <query_term>
 |     <query_expression> EXCEPT [ ALL ] [ <corresponding_spec> ] <query_term>
```

Therefore, using `ORDER BY` in an individual query expression in a `UNION ALL` clause is syntactically incorrect; there are no other similar query clauses that must not be used in a `UNION`.